# How to show minimum 10 rows in rich faces extendedDataTable with a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Suppose I have more than 10 rows of data to display in a richfaces extendedDataTable component and I want to show minimum 10 rows on initial load. And if the user wants to see the remaining rows, the user have to scroll down using the vertical scrollbar.
The code which I used is given below.

```
<rich:layout position="center" style="overflow:hidden">
        <rich:layoutPanel position="center" >
                <rich:extendedDataTable enableContextMenu="false" 
                    style="vertical-align: top; horizontal-align: center; "
                    id="filtertable" value="#{dynamicBean.selectedData.filterDetList}"
                    var="bdata" height="#{reportDesignerBean.height}"
                    showWhenRendered="false" rowClasses="datatable-odd,datatable-even"
                    selectedClass="grid-selection-style"
                    noDataLabel="#{msg['bnp.common.extendedDataTable.noDataLabel']}">

                    <rich:column width="110px">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['bnp.reortdesign.customreport.sqlreports.columnname']}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:panelGrid id="filterName">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bdata.columnLabel}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column width="110px" style="text-align:center;" >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['bnp.reortdesign.customreport.sqlreports.isafilter']}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkOne" value="#{bdata.rowSelected}"  >              
                            <a4j:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true">                      
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bdata}" value="#{bdata}"/>
                            </a4j:support>

                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column width="320px">
                        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="#{msg['bnp.reortdesign.customreport.sqlreports.filtervalue']}" /></f:facet>
                        <h:panelGrid width="380px" id="filtervalue" columns="3">
                        ${bdata.columnDataType}
                        <c:if test="#{bdata.columnDataType != 'Date'}">
                            <h:inputText value="#{bdata.value}" maxlength="150"
                                style="width:240px">
                                <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bdata}" value="#{bdata}"/>
                                </a4j:support>
                            </h:inputText>
                        </c:if> 
                        <c:if test="#{bdata.columnDataType == 'Date'}"  >
                            <rich:calendar id="fixedDateValue" datePattern="#{loginBean.userPrefVO.preferredDateFmt}"
                                           value="#{bdata.value}" buttonIcon="true" showWeeksBar="false"
                                           weekDayLabelsShort="Su,Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa"
                                           oninputfocus="#{rich:component('fixedDateValue')}.doExpand();"
                                           onclick="#{rich:component('fixedDateValue')}.doExpand()" width="20px"
                                           buttonClass="calendar-button-style">
                                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="#{loginBean.userPrefVO.preferredDateFmt}" />
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="50%"
                                                 columnClasses="fake, width100 talign">
                                        <h:outputText value="{previousMonthControl}"
                                                      style="font-weight:bold;" />
                                        <h:outputText value="{currentMonthControl}"
                                                      style="font-weight:normal;padding-left:15px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer"
                                                      disabled="true" />
                                        <h:outputText value="{nextMonthControl}"
                                                      style="font-weight:bold;" />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="fixedDateValue" style=""></f:facet>
                            </rich:calendar>
                        </c:if>
                            <rich:spacer width="20px" />                
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column width="205px">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg['bnp.reortdesign.customreport.sqlreports.datatype']}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:panelGrid id="filterdatatype">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bdata.columnDataType}"  style="color:green;font-style: italic;font-size:10px;"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:extendedDataTable>
                <!-- <a4j:outputPanel id="fScrollerPanel">       
                    <rich:datascroller id="filterScroller" for="filtertable"  ></rich:datascroller>       
                </a4j:outputPanel> -->
            </rich:layoutPanel>     
        </rich:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Richfaces showcase:](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable)

> In order to turn on Ajax loading - you should just specify **clientRows** attribute with number of rows to be loaded on the client. In the sample below it's set to 15 or to 0 according to checkbox value. 0 value means load all the rows (or attribute could be just not defined at all).

Comment: You should mention that this only works in RichFaces 4; the code provided above suggests OP is using RichFaces 3.

Comment: :-)... I 'should' not mention that, I did a quick google and found this showcase example. The OP could (should?) have done that and mention these things... But point taken...

Comment: I want to show all the rows but minimum 10 rows when the scroll position is at the top.